# Spark Scala - how to create DF out of messy .txt

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I am completely new in Big Data, please keep it simple.

Using Scala I have loaded .txt file, which content looks like this:
[click][1]

```
import scala.io.Source
val lines = Source.fromFile("C:/Users/me/Downloads/myText.txt ").getLines().toList
```

In any case, as per task I should receive DataFrame in result, so I've done the following:

```
lines.toDF()
```

The result is:

```
+------------------------------+
|value                         |
+------------------------------+
|+---+------------------+-----+|
|| id|             Text1|Text2||
|+---+------------------+-----+|
||  1|     one,two,three|  one||
||  2|     four,one,five|  six||
||  3|seven,nine,one,two|eight||
||  4|    two,three,five| five||
||  5|      six,five,one|seven||
|+---+------------------+-----+|
+------------------------------+
```

While my goal is:

```
+---+------------------+-----+
|id |Text1             |Text2|
+---+------------------+-----+
|1  |one,two,three     |one  |
|2  |four,one,five     |six  |
|3  |seven,nine,one,two|eight|
|4  |two,three,five    |five |
|5  |six,five,one      |seven|
+---+------------------+-----+
```

Could you suggest me the tools/methods to achieve it?

Comment: Could you first few lines of your `myText.txt` details? That'd be helpful

Comment: Here is the content for .txt :+---+------------------+-----+
| id|             Text1|Text2|
+---+------------------+-----+
|  1|     one,two,three|  one|
|  2|     four,one,five|  six|
|  3|seven,nine,one,two|eight|
|  4|    two,three,five| five|
|  5|      six,five,one|seven|
+---+------------------+-----+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code should help you. Basically I'm creating an RDD, applying on the required filters and thereby converting it into a DataFrame.

```
//Upto you as how many partitions you want depending on the data instead of 5
val myRDD = spark.sparkContext.textFile("mytext.txt", 5) 
                           .filter{x => !{ x.contains("-") || x.contains("+") || x.contains("id")}}
                           .map { y => y.substring(1, y.length()-2) }
                           .map { z => z.split("\\|") }
                           .map { a => Row(a(0), a(1), a(2))  } 

val schema = new StructType()
                    .add(StructField("id", StringType, true))
                    .add(StructField("Text1", StringType, true))
                    .add(StructField("Text2", StringType, true))

val myDF = spark.createDataFrame(myRDD, schema)

myDF.show()
```

I'm simply filtering all the non-required files that is there in the data, converting them into RDD of [Row](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row) and thereby converting it into a dataframe using explicit schema definition.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Hey, that's a very clear answer, thank you! I've uploaded the result, it is quite unexpected. :/ Can you have a look once more?

Comment: @EstherMallow Please check. I believe the above code should run well for this.

Comment: @EstherMallow Was the above solution useful? Did it resolve what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, it worked!!! Thank you very much. I went through the code thoroughly to understand the logic and methods. There two parts I am a little bit confused with. 1) Why after split method I cannot print the lines and see the intermediate result? I have to apply next step as well to see content.  2) Why the type of the first column is String, if it contains numbers only? I tried to change this StructField to IntegerType, but received an error.

Comment: @EstherMallow Happy to hear that!! Feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer by clicking on the greyed our arrow on the left.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to upvote :) But your answer is great, thank you.  Could you also have a quick look on my questions above?

Comment: 1. Could you share me the code where you were unable to write println statements 2. Note the first row of your data, you have special characters. As a result all the values are considered as string. If your data has only `headers` and `values` and not '+---+------------------+-----+` it would have inferred as what you expect. For that reason, you have to write another job itself to ensure that data is `saved` in proper format, that way you will avoid such clean up acts while running another subsequent jobs where business dependent functions would be called, thus making it efficient.

Answer (score 0):

File can be read, wrong lines are filtered, and new dataset created with "csv":

```
val textFileDataSet = spark.read.text(fileName).as(Encoders.STRING)

val textWithoutUnderlines = textFileDataSet
  .filter(!_.contains("-"))
  .map(l => l.substring(1, l.length - 2))

val result = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").csv(textWithoutUnderlines)
```